# Create a dynamic string variable from a configuration text file in bash script

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I want to create a dynamic string variable that holds file extension from a configuration text file like this. The bad thing is that the string value contains regex expression:

```
EXCLUDE_EXTENSION="\.(log|txt|png)$"
```

where the log, txt and png extensions I get it from a text file called excluded_ext.txt. So the content of the excluded_ext.txt is:

```
log
txt
png
```

so whenever I add another extension in excluded_ext.txt, I will get an updated extension inside the variable EXCLUDE_EXTENSION. Example if I add an extra extension of 'log' inside excluded_ext.txt

```
log
txt
png
log
```

then the value of variable EXCLUDE_EXTENSION should be updated automatically to:

```
EXCLUDE_EXTENSION="\.(log|txt|png|log)$"
```

I think I might need to use regex but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```
#!/bin/sh
# read from a text file
EXCLUDED_TEXT=`cat excluded_ext.txt`
# create array from the text file
# Im not sure how to go next.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `paste` and a command substitution:

```
EXCLUDE_EXTENSION='\.('"$(paste -d'|' -s excluded_ext.txt)"')$'
```

Comment: never thought about the paste command. tq.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash (as per your title) rather than `sh` (as shown in your code snippet), then you should be able to do something like this:

```
mapfile -t exts < excluded_ext.txt        # this creates the array

OldIFS="$IFS"
IFS='|'
printf -v exclude_extension '\.(%s)$' "${exts[*]}"
IFS="$OldIFS"

echo "$exclude_extension"
```

`"${exts[*]}"` expands to the elements of `exts`, separated by the first character of the current `IFS`.

Comment: tq so much, i wish to upvote this answer but i have no right.